# Cannot draw freehand lines (pencil) in Gimp - lines are straight/diagonal?

Tags: gimp

I have used GIMP for ages, and I've NEVER seen this before...

When I try to make a freehand line, it comes out all jaggy, since somehow horizontal/vertical/45 degree lines are preferred apparently:

[image]

What is this and how can I get it deactivated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your brush is snapping to the image grid. Reset with `View > Snap to grid`

On my system, with "snap to grid" enabled (left) and disabled (right):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help - that was it, works for me!